# iOS splash screen black window

Tags: ios, uiview, splash-screen, uiwindow

Hi I just wondered if it is possible to change the colour of the black view that appears when you first launch an app. I am using a transparent splash screen image and wondered if possible to change the colour of this view/window or whatever it is before your app is launched. The reason I ask is because my app can be skinned for several clients and they have particular colour schemes. It would save me time having to remake a splash image with there chosen colour if this makes sense? Thats why I use a transparent splash...if not I will just have to remake the image with the colours required however my whole app colours can be changed in an instant minus the above requirement.

Comment: your default.png file is the splash screen and you might change the color of it however you want.

Comment: @gulliver007 thanks I know this but if you look at my question I am using a transparent image which shows the black behind and wondered if possible to change this black if not ill just remake splashed in required colours.

Comment: I doubt that, I feel changing the default.png to some non-transparent colored image would be the way to go

Comment: @gulliver007 thanks I didnt think it could be but thought id ask. Oh well just have to make images for clients in there colour rather than doing it in code.

Comment: You cannot modify the background color of Loading screen. By default it will be in black color

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The splash screen will *ALWAYS* show the default image defined in your application bundle.
**It can be nothing else.** You will have to create the image for each version of the application.

Comment: Yes I use a splash image its transparent the question was the black colour you see behind the splash image..if it cant be changed then as you say I will just have to make different coloured images for client. Thanks

Comment: There's no way around this. Accept my answer if it answers your question please.

Answer (score 0):

When creating a new iOS iPhone application, Xcode will create 3 splash screen files for you in "Supporting Files" group, named

- Default.png
- Default@2x.png
- Default-568h@2x.png

These files are the splash screens for iPhone 3G/3GS, iPhone 4/4S and iPhone 5 respectively.
By default these are black images. You can replace them with whatever images you want for splash screen.
Make sure that you keep names the same.

Comment: Sorry I dont think people are understanding the question. If you drop a default.png image that is TRANSPARENT it will load it fine thats all good no problem. I wondered if the view BEHIND the splash because its transparent can it have its colour changed without having to make image with colour embedded I want to change the colour via code if possible.

Comment: Through reading this: [link]http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/userexperience/conceptual/mobilehig/IconsImages/IconsImages.html I think you should not use transparency in application icons and splash screen.

Comment: yes I didnt think it would be ok I will just make custom images for each client rather than trying to be clever.